# Regex to match a string inside quotes and exclude empty string and whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have regex, that unfortunately include empty strings also.

```
var regex = new Regex("\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

Comment: Please post the input and desired output examples

Comment: Your data does not seem to include any `"`, Ксения. Also, I suspect you use `regex.Split(str)` while you wanted `regex.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`.

Comment: There is no reason to use Regex.  Just use string split method which is more efficient.  Then use just a straight string compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by `"` and get the odd elements :

```
string[] result = str.Split('"').Where((s, i) => (i & 1) > 0 && s != "").ToArray();
```

results in:

```
Январь
Февраль
Март
Апрель
Май
Июнь
Июль
Август
Сентябрь
Октябрь
Ноябрь
Декабрь
Всего рабочих дней
Всего праздничных и выходных дней
Количество рабочих часов при 40-часовой рабочей неделе
Количество рабочих часов при 36-часовой рабочей неделе
Количество рабочих часов при 24-часовой рабочей неделе
1,2,3,4,6*,7,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31
6,7,13,14,20,21,27,28
6,7,8,13,14,20,21,27,28
3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25,30*
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,15,16,22,23,29,30
5,6,11*,12,13,14,19,20,26,27
3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25,31
1,7,8,14,15,21,22,28,29
4,5,11,12,18,19,25,26
2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31
6,7,8,13,14,20,21,27,28
4,5,11,12,13,18,19,25,26,31*
1,2,3,4,6*,7,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30
5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27
4,5,7*,8,11,12,18,19,25,26
1,2,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30
1,2,6,7,8*,9,13,14,20,21,27,28
3,4,10,11,12,17,18,24,25
1,2,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30
5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27
2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30
1,7,8,14,15,21,22,28,29
4,5,7,11,12,18,19,25,26
2,3,9,10,11*,12,16,17,23,24,30,31
1,2,6,7,8,13,14,20,21,27,28
3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25
3,4,7*,8,10,11,17,18,24,25,31
1,7,8,14,15,21,22,28,29,30*
1,2,5,6,8*,9,12,13,19,20,26,27
2,3,9,10,11*,12,16,17,23,24,30
1,7,8,14,15,21,22,28,29
4,5,11,12,18,19,25,26
1,2,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30
6,7,13,14,20,21,27,28
3,4,6*,7,10,11,17,18,24,25
1,2,8,9,12,15,16,22,23,29,30
```